# Remember brush size when switching between brushes in Krita

Tags: brush, krita

Usually when I draw, I frequently switch between two or three tools and/or brushes. By default in Krita (I've tried versions 2.8.5 and 2.9.10), brush size is reset to default when selecting a brush. So, if I use a tool A, set it's size, when switch to a tool B and then back to A, A's size is reset to default. It's very annoying to adjust the size each time, especially when working on smaller scale for long periods of time.

Is there a way to fix that? I set two keys on my tablet to increase/decrease the size, but still I waste a lot of time pressing them for no good reason. Shift+drag is also inconvenient, because I set my keyboard pretty far back on the desk.

If that's not possible, what is the common way to deal with brush sizes? I know I can use presets, but creating a preset just to use a different size seems like an overkill.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To save the brush size of a preset, you have to enable the "Temporarily save tweaks to presets" check box in the brush editor

Assuming you are on the latest version of Krita, Press **F5** and then just click on the check-box which says **"Temporarily save tweaks to presets"** as shown in the image below.

This will make sure your tweaks or changes to the brush preset such as opacity flow size are remembered until you close Krita

[image]